# I cannot list large directory

Tags: linux, bash, glusterfs

I've a large directory (very large), in where ls is not working, I've also tried iterate it with for, and NO luck.

This directory is in a gluster volume... Any idea?

More information:

- Gluster vol is mounted in fstab with simple options.
- I've tried for f in * ; do something with $f ; done
- Now I'm trying rsync -a --delete empty-dir/ my-dir/

regards

Comment: Have you tried `/bin/ls` without any arguments on it?

Comment: yes sr.! this was the first I've tried... Now I'm running a for and it's taking 12 hs and running :(

Comment: How did you use (or `mount`) your `glusterfs` ?

Comment: How *exactly* have you run `ls`? Are you sure it is not some `alias` ? Have you tried *exactly* `/bin/ls > /tmp/ls.out` ? Or `/bin/ls -f > /tmp/unsorted-ls.out` ?

Comment: I guess that your  `for` loop (which is not entirely mentioned in your question) won't answer. You want `/bin/ls -f` which is probably the fastest.

Comment: I'm mounting my fs simply in the fstab defaults,_netdev,backupvolfile-server=my2nd. I'm now trying /bin/ls -f as you suggested...

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53806058/edit) your question to improve it. Don't give these important details only in comments. In general, avoid commenting your own question!

Comment: `for f in *` is bad for big list of arguments. You can try `find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' -r f`

Answer (score 2):

You almost certainly could use system calls (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) and related functions, e.g. [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) (they internally use [getdents(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html) that you don't want to use directly), `closedir`, [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html), or [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) on that; of course you'll need to write a specific program (perhaps in C, or at least in Python).

Next time, even for huge (petabyte sized) file systems, take care to avoid more than a few thousand entries per directory (so organize your files like `00/00/0001.jpeg` .... `01/23/4567.jpeg` and so on, not `00000001.jpeg` ... `01234567.jpeg` and so on in a single directory). If you keep small sized directories (even in petabyte sized filesystems) you'll make your shell happier and more usable (and perhaps even your kernel).

However, recent file systems like EXT4 or BTRFS are capable to have many millions of entries in a directory. But shells (and [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), see [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)...) are unhappy with that. My guess would be that `/bin/ls` *without arguments* (or at least `/bin/ls -f` to get an *unsorted* listing) should work (see [ls(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html)).

Some file systems, even when capable of many millions of entries per directory, may need a linear time to access them (see [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html), [ext4(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html) etc...), or else you might need to supply specific arguments to [mount(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) (e.g. `dir_index` for `ext4`).

Remember that globbing is done by your shell before calling [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), which does have limitations (generally, a few hundred thousands bytes at most for program arguments, so no more than a few thousand of *expanded* arguments to a program, otherwise `execve` fails with `E2BIG`).

Comment: `getdents` man page has a nice sample program that I used once in a similar situation.